# Plain text email source code only contains a long meaningless string as its contents, but can be displayed in thunderbird in meaningful texts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I've received such a few such emails from one single person recently: Thunderbird and the web mail displays normal texts (real contents of the email), but when I click the "view source code" button, only a long string is there in the content part (no obvious real contents!), after the email headers. The style of the long string is similar to a PGP key in ASCII, but no PGP is used in the emails. The sender's mail agent is Outlook.

What is happening here? Is there a special format used here?

Comment: Do you use any OpenPGP product? It looks like the message might have been encrypted to you. Please post the email payload (the part after the email headers) with a small excerpt of the contents.

Comment: @dr01 I've added a snippet. I use GPG locally, but I'm not using it on the Webmail, which can also display the contents.

Comment: @dr01 I removed the contents; I saw it's base64 encoding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email is encoded using base64:

```
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```